# Not able to insert the record in to SQLITE3 DB with tortoise ORM in fastAPI APP

Tags: fastapi, tortoise-orm

```
await room.save()
```

showing the below error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute_insert'

startUp code

```
async def init():
    # Here we create a SQLite DB using file "db.sqlite3"
    #  also specify the app name of "models"
    #  which contain models from "app.models"
    await Tortoise.init(
        db_url='sqlite://db1',
        modules={'app1': ['app1.models']}
    )
    # Generate the schema
    #await Tortoise.generate_schemas()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
  nest_asyncio.apply()
  run_async(init())
```

created a db structure that's why commented await Tortoise.generate_schemas().
Find my post method code below

```
@app.post("/room/{room_id}")
async def post(request: Request, room_id):
      room = models.Room(id=room_id)
      await room.save()
      return {"message":"created successfully"}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `@app.on_event("startup")` which is an async function, you are calling `run_async(init())` which according to the [documentation](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#the-importance-of-cleaning-up) cleans up after itself, and is meant for small scripts only.
Meaning you are creating and then destroying the DB connection. Hence the connection being a `None`.

Instead, just await it, and handle shutdown event like so:

```py
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
  nest_asyncio.apply()
  await init()

@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def close_orm():
    await Tortoise.close_connections()
```

Edit: Apparently there is also issues with `nest_asyncio` and [just leaving it out makes things work better.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991357/how-do-i-stop-valueerror-tortoise-backends-sqlite-client-sqliteclient-object-w)