# How do I stop "ValueError: tortoise.backends.sqlite.client.SqliteClient object was created in a different Context"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, tortoise-orm

I'm writing a discord bot and using tortoise orm to store data. I need to use transactions, but I continually get the following error:

```py
Full type of the error is <class 'discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError'>
Command raised an exception: ValueError: <Token var=<ContextVar name='default' default=<tortoise.backends.sqlite.client.SqliteClient object at 0x7f52ef5080d0> at 0x7f52ef362630> at 0x7f52dd636c80> was created in a different Context
- [x] Traceback (most recent call last):
- [x]   File "/home/minion/PycharmProjects/Gone-Pair-Shaped/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 83, in wrapped
- [x]     ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
- [x]   File "/home/minion/PycharmProjects/CAHRewrite/cogs/terms/__init__.py", line 137, in agree
- [x]     await guild.save(using_db=guild_creation)
- [x]   File "/home/minion/PycharmProjects/Gone-Pair-Shaped/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tortoise/backends/base/client.py", line 233, in __aexit__
- [x]     current_transaction_map[self.connection_name].reset(self.token)
- [x] ValueError: <Token var=<ContextVar name='default' default=<tortoise.backends.sqlite.client.SqliteClient object at 0x7f52ef5080d0> at 0x7f52ef362630> at 0x7f52dd636c80> was created in a different Context
- [x] 
- [x] The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
- [x] 
- [x] Traceback (most recent call last):
- [x]   File "/home/minion/PycharmProjects/Gone-Pair-Shaped/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 892, in invoke
- [x]     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
- [x]   File "/home/minion/PycharmProjects/Gone-Pair-Shaped/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 797, in invoke
- [x]     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
- [x]   File "/home/minion/PycharmProjects/Gone-Pair-Shaped/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 92, in wrapped
- [x]     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
- [x] discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: <Token var=<ContextVar name='default' default=<tortoise.backends.sqlite.client.SqliteClient object at 0x7f52ef5080d0> at 0x7f52ef362630> at 0x7f52dd636c80> was created in a different Context
- [x]
```

I'm creating my transactions like so, in a discord ext.commands command

```py
        async with tortoise.transactions.in_transaction() as guild_creation:
            default_game_settings = database.guild.GameDefaults()
            await default_game_settings.save(using_db=guild_creation)
            settings = database.guild.GuildSettings()
            await settings.save(using_db=guild_creation)
            guild = database.guild.Guild(
                guild_id=ctx.guild.id,
                agreed_at=datetime.datetime.now(),
                agreed_by=ctx.author.id,
                default_settings=default_game_settings,
                settings=settings,
            )
            await guild.save(using_db=guild_creation)
```

I've also tried to start my transactions with a function, which results in the same error. My question is: what does `ValueError: <Token var=<ContextVar name='default' default=<tortoise.backends.sqlite.client.SqliteClient object at 0x7f52ef5080d0> at 0x7f52ef362630> at 0x7f52dd636c80> was created in a different Context` mean, and how do I get it to go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out my issue!
While going through my code and seeing what could be interfering I found that I was using `nest_asyncio`, which I didn't believe to be an issue

Having removed the module, the code now works